# ES5とES6のどちらを学ぶべき？

Tags: javascript, es6

こんにちは、JavaScriptを学び始めた者です。

オンラインで学習するサイトで学習を始めたのですが、ES6とES5でレッスンが分かれていました。
これから学ぼうという者はES6だけ学習すれば良いのでしょうか？
それともES5も学習しておいた方が良いのでしょうか？

お詳しい方、お教えいただけたらと思います。
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: タイトルには自己紹介では無く **具体的な質問内容** を記載することを心がけてください。質問は後からでも [編集] できるので、必要に応じて見直してみてください。 / 参考ヘルプ: [良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

こんにちは、はじめまして。
基本的には用途によるかと思います。

とはいえブラウザ上やnode.jsでの実行に関しては末尾最適化を除けば
2020年では問題ないようですし、学習するのはES6で差し支えないと思います。
https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

ただし、お勤めの場合はご周囲にあわせたほうが良いと思います。
ES5よりももっと古い仕様で記述されたコードにも現場やインターネットでは遭遇しますので、
将来的には過去のソースも理解できるようにしたほうがよいと思います。

追記 : コメントでいただきましたが、ES5のみサポートとなるIE11のシェアはまだ日本国内では12%あるそうです(世界では3%)。フロントエンド開発の現場では、ES5を考慮したコーディング、もしくはBavelなどのトランスパイラを利用する必要が、今後数年のスパンでまだあると思います。

Comment: Kouki.W様　ご回答ありがとうございます！まずはES6だけ学習して、必要な場面に出くわしたらES5の学習もしようと思います。

ありがとうございました！

Comment: 2020年1月でもES6に対応していないIE11のシェアが日本国内ではまだ12.14%もあることについて言及しておくべきかと思います。 https://webrage.jp/techblog/pc_browser_share/ (リンク先は更新されている可能性あり)